# Запрос: Обновить поле в зависимости другого поля

Tags: sql

Почему-то не хочет работать запрос:

```sql
UPDATE table SET field1 = IF(field2 = 0, 1, field1) WHERE id = ' . $id;
```

Правильно ли я его построил? Нужно в зависимости от значения поля записать в него другое значение или оставить прежнее.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Может так?

```sql
UPDATE table 
   SET field1 = CASE
  WHEN field2 = 0 THEN 1
  ELSE field1
END
```

Answer (score 0):

```sql
SELECT CASE <variable> WHEN <value>      THEN <returnvalue>
                       WHEN <othervalue> THEN <returnthis>
                                     ELSE <returndefaultcase>
       END
FROM <table>
```

Подстройте под себя.

Comment: Это же `Select` а нужен `Update`

Comment: Я автора поставил в правильное направление, сам код он напишет сам.

Answer (score 0):

Мне кажется, что в запросе просто не хватает одной буковки:

```sql
UPDATE table SET field1 = IIF(field2 = 0, 1, field1) WHERE id = ' . $id;
```

[Функция IIF](http://www.sql-tutorial.ru/ru/book_case_statement/page4.html)